# How to stop execution after a certain time

Tags: android, countdowntimer, execution-time

I have a function that is continuously looking for active services on the network with its name and port, but it is endless.

I would like to know how to stop the execution after 30 seconds or something like that. Since the original method has no stop mechanism.

I don't have code yet to publish, because I don't know where to start with this.

Thank you for any advice.